# CDATA not working in RSS Title

Tags: rss, title, cdata

cdata is not working in title. it is working in description !

```
            <item>
        <title>Line and <![CDATA[<br />]]>breaked line</title>
        <pubDate>09 Jun 2010</pubDate>
        <description>Line and <![CDATA[<br />]]>breaked line</description>
        <category>cat</category>
    </item>
```

Answer (score 0):

In what way is it not working? I imagine that most RSS clients won't render HTML in a `<title>` tag, anyway (especially not line breaks).